# mosquitto cannot assign requested address in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mosquitto

I've an php application with docker environment, everything works fine but now, I want to install `mosquitto` broker in my `php` container

This is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        ports:
            - "8288:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
            - ./dockers/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on:
            - php
    php:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockers/php/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/
            - ./dockers/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf
        ports:
            - 9004:9000
            - 1883:1883
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: access-control-mysql
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "7306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

This is `Dockerfile` which build `php` container

```
FROM 8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update -yqq

# Install & enable Xdebug for code coverage reports
RUN pecl install xdebug imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug imagick

RUN apt-get install -y mosquitto libmosquitto-dev
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Add script file to run command
COPY scripts/cmd.sh /usr/local/bin/cmd
RUN chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/cmd

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/cmd"]
```

Then `mosquitto.conf`

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

When I start all container, it works fine. However, mosquitto seem not work and when I check mosquitto by command `docker-compose exec php mosquitto`, it display error:

```
1669015395: mosquitto version 2.0.11 starting
1669015395: Using default config.
1669015395: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1669015395: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1669015395: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
1669015395: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1669015395: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1669015395: Error: Cannot assign requested address
1669015395: mosquitto version 2.0.11 running
```

It shows error `Error: Cannot assign requested address`, I've use the same config with separate mosquitto container in `docker-compose.yaml` file and it worked.

Mosquitto container in docker-compose

```
    mqtt:
      image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
      ports:
        - 1884:1883
      volumes:
        - ./dockers/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
        - ./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
        - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
```

I also try add `bind_address` into listener in `mosquitto.conf`: `listener 1883 [php container ip]` but it return same error.

Can someone help? Thanks.

##### Update

- File `cmd.sh`

```
    /usr/local/bin/composer install
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan migrate
    php artisan ide-helper:generate
    php artisan ide-helper:models --nowrite
    php artisan db:seed
    php-fpm
```

Comment: What is in `/usr/loca/bin/cmd`? Also what is the log output from the `php` container? The exec command is running mosquitto without a config file (and likely as a second instance)

Comment: @hardillb `cmd` start php-fpm server and executes some artisan command (updated in post). And no error from `php` container log output, only output from command run in `cmd.sh`

Comment: @hardillb `The exec command is running mosquitto without a config file (and likely as a second instance)`, I've volumed `mosquitto.conf` into `conf.d`  in `mosquitto` folder, I think it will use volumed config file, doesn't it?

Comment: No, mosquitto has **NO** default config, you always have to explicitly pass it the path to the config file.

Comment: You also appear to mixing `cmd` with `cmd.sh`, neither of which explicitly start mosquitto, so you need to check if there is a systemd service running in your container to start it as a service. To be honest I would not try and mix the PHP and mosquitto in the same container. Part of the point of containers is to separate things like this. Just run the broker in it's own container.

Comment: @hardillb, sorry for late reply. `No, mosquitto has NO default config,...`, this weird, because  when I check folder installed mosquitto in `/etc/mosquitto`, there is `mosquitto.conf` file default when install app, if I have to pass config file path, I have to point to this file, dont I?

Comment: `You also appear to mixing cmd with cmd.sh...`, There 2 files are the same, `cmd` is copied from `cmd.sh` into docker container.

Comment: And with systemd, it seem `systemd` cannot work in docker container but when I try to start service by command `/usr/sbin/mosquitto` it return same error when i execute command `mosquitto`: `Error: Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying to install this [mosquitto-php](https://mosquitto-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in php container, but it seem not work with mosquitto in separate container, thus, I'm trying to install mosquitto in php container

Answer (score 0):

mosquitto-php does not require you to run the broker in the same container, it's pre-requisite is libmosquitto which can be installed with just

```
RUN apt-get install -y libmosquitto-dev
```

You should then run the broker for your project from the `eclipse-mosquitto` container, not try and include it directly into the php container.

And for clarity, as I said in the comments mosquitto will not load ANY configuration file unless explicitly told where the file is with the `-c` command line option. Just because `/etc/mosquitto.conf` exists doesn't mean it will get loaded, unless you run `mosquitto -c /etc/mosqutto.conf`. This is why the logs you showed explicitly say it is not using any config file.

```
1669015395: Using default config.
1669015395: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
```